# What to use as WCF net.tcp host baseAddress on different servers?

Tags: wcf

In my App.config, i have this base address specified ("jerrycan" is the name of my computer):

```xml
<service behaviorConfiguration="helloWorldServiceBehavior" name="OpdService.OpdService">
    <endpoint address="/service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
      name="MainEndPoint" contract="OpdService.IOpdService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="jerrycan" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://jerrycan:8000" />
        <add baseAddress="http://jerrycan/service" />
      </baseAddresses>
      <timeouts openTimeout="00:00:15" />
    </host>
  </service>
```

Everything works fine until I run service on other computer — clients can find service through UDP discovery, but aren't able to connect, as service continues to send old address. When I change "jerrycan" to "localhost", only local clients are able to connect to service (but on any computer). Any clients on other computers try to connect to "localhost" with no success.

So what should I use as host address if I want to be able to run service on different computers without recompile? Should I store address somewhere in config file for every computer, or should I change address in runtime? I think, I'm missing something simple and fundamental here.

Or maybe I should use localhost (as in many wcf samples) and it's my client connection code  who brings the problems:

```cs
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = findResponse.Endpoints[0].Address;
OpdChannelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<OpdServiceReference.IOpdService>(CallbackHandler,
                        new NetTcpBinding("MainEndPoint"), endpointAddress);
```

Again, when I use "localhost" as base address, "localhost" comes as endpoint address in `findResponse`.

**Edit:**

It seems like **I found solution** here: http://btw-blog.blogspot.com/2011/02/dynamic-base-address-for-wcf-service.html

The point is to replace host name in base address with * symbol (wildcard). It will be changed with actual host name in run time.

Haven't tested everything yet, but looks like it actually works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like I found solution here: http://btw-blog.blogspot.com/2011/02/dynamic-base-address-for-wcf-service.html

The point is to replace host name in base address with "*" symbol (wildcard). It will be changed with actual host name in run time.

Tested it and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your service endpoint address is:

`net.tcp://jerrycan:8000/service`

When you create clients on the computer which is hosting the service (jerrycan-pc) of course the local clients will be able to access the service by referencing

`net.tcp://localhost:8000/service`

and obviously other clients (on other computers on your network) **can not** connect to the service if they try to contact **localhost**, because the endpoint: `net.tcp://localhost:8000/service`, is calling the local computer which in this case is not hosting the service (only for jerrycan-pc). If `jerrycan-pc` is hosting the service, clients on `jerrycan-pc` can call the service by referencing `localhost`, but clients on say `mike-pc` must either try to call `jerrycan-pc` or `jerrycan-pc`'s IP. If you change the endpoint in your service configuration to your service hosts IP or even computer name, and reference the service on other computers using the IP of the service host/computer name then they will be able to access it. For example if jerrycan-pc is hosting the service and it has an IP of `192.168.1.5`, your clients can consume the service by referencing this endpoint:

`net.tcp://192.168.1.5:8000/service`

So in your service config change `localhost` to the IP address or PC name and try to contact that address on your clients instead of contacting `localhost`.

Comment: add jerrycan to the hosts file of your other PCs and it'll find it too.

Comment: I want to run service on different computers, sometimes even in the same time (I use scopes to distinguish services). When I use PC name or IP as host address, I can't run service on other computers. Also, I use WS-discovery to find active service, so I can't use one or another address on clients, I just have to use whatever comes with findResponse. And findResponse just gives what is declared in service app.config (I don't know why).

Comment: Found the solution, for more information see update in question.